# Recording Research Logs / Plans

Tags: research-methods, software-recommendations

I am looking for some guidance on how best to record the research I have completed so I do not duplicate the same research. I will also use the logs to plan future research.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a good programme to record my research.

I currently use Family Historian to record my tree.

Comment: Have you looked at the Research Planner plugin for Family Historian: https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=how_to:research_planner. Disclosure: I wrote it. It won't be what you want if you want a standalone programme.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at that and it maybe a possibility though I was really looking for a stand-alone programme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a spreadsheet application to manage research contacts (columns: name, contact info, aim, result) and TaskPaper (macOS, https://www.taskpaper.com) to outline future research. TaskPaper is plain text based, making it future-proof. It has extremely good filtering possibilities, can be extended by scripts and adopted to personal preferences regarding the style. Names, places, etc can be set as *tags*, making it easy to show different tasks related e.g. to one place or archive.